# Google cloud error when deploying container: environment variable is missing

Tags: postgresql, docker, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, gcloud

When trying to deploy my docker container to Google cloud I got the error `(RuntimeError) environment variable DATABASE_URL is missing.` even though I had successfully set the `DATABASE_URL` variable using the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables).

This error happens after I run the command `gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/backend --platform managed` any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set environment variables for Cloud Run `gcloud run ...`, using the instructions here:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--set-env-vars

Something of the form:

```sh
gcloud run deploy ${NAME} \
--image=gcr.io/${PROJECT-ID} \
--set-env-vars=DATABASE_URL="[[DATABASE-URL]]" \
...
```

The instructions you reference are for Cloud Composer which is a different Google service and it has different requirements.

If you'd like a more specific answer, please include more details about what you're trying to do, how you do it (please include commands that you used) and what happened (please include the output|errors from the commands).